# Select new object from IQueryable returns part of list in a case

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to select a list of new objects from an `IQueryable`. When a specific parameter from that `IQueryable` is `null`, it returns the list but that object.

```
var companyName = "Company";    

var gridObjects = iQueryableObjectList.Select(obj => 
    new GridObject
    {
        AddedByEmployeeId = obj.AddedByEmployeeId,
        AddedByEmployeeSignature = obj.AddedByEmployee.Signature,
        AddedDateTime = obj.Created,
        DocumentId = obj.DocumentId,
        ResponsibleEmployeeId = obj.ResponsibleEmployeeId,
        ResponsibleEmployee = obj.ResponsibleEmployeeId != null ? 
            obj.ResponsibleEmployee.FirstName + " " + obj.ResponsibleEmployee.LastName :
            companyName,
        Id = obj.Id,
        IsCompanyWide = obj.IsCompanyWide
    });
```

`iQueryableObjectList` contains 6 objects of type `ObjectItem`. A single one of them has the `ResponsibleEmployeeId` value set as `null`.

After this select statement, `gridObjects` contains 5 elements, all from `iQueryableObjectList` except that one that has `ResponsibleEmployeeId` value set as `null`.

I mention that `ResponsibleEmployeeId` is a `Guid?` in both classes, `ObjectItem` and `GridObject`.

If I remove this:

```
ResponsibleEmployeeId = obj.ResponsibleEmployeeId,
ResponsibleEmployee = obj.ResponsibleEmployeeId != null ? 
    obj.ResponsibleEmployee.FirstName + " " + obj.ResponsibleEmployee.LastName :
    companyName,
```

from that select statement, then it returns 6 elements.

Does anyone has an idea about this? Please ask for additional info if needed.

EDIT: problem solved. In some configuration mapping of that entity `ResponsibleEmployeeId` was required so when EF saw that it had a null value, it simply ignored it.

Comment: Can you reproduce it if you materialize collection before select, like `iQueryableObjectList.ToArray().Select(...`? I suspect implementation details of specific `IQueryable`

Comment: Well, I can't do that here. Because after I make the select I use a framework that does sort and filter on the list and in order to work it needs to be IQueryable.

Comment: What does "it returns the list but that object" mean?

Comment: First of all can a Guid be null? That doesn't seem like appropriate behaviour. Your input is a IQueryable list of ObjectItems, you use select in order to change them into GridObjects. That's cool. The second line that you remove is an if statement are you aware of that?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue. Can you create and share small project with your problem? What if you remove just the first line: `ResponsibleEmployeeId = obj.ResponsibleEmployeeId,`?

Comment: What is the source & type for iQueryableObjectList? Is this an IQueryable<> from an ORM? (EF/NHibernate/Linq2SQL,etc)

Comment: @Enigmativity returns 5 elements instead of 6

Comment: @pijemcolu Yes, it's a nullable Guid because it is not required. Yes I am aware, I just tested to see what causes the problem.

Comment: @Artholl If I remove just the first line it still causes that problem

Comment: @StevePy it is from EF

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've had a similar problem with EF when it comes to resolving related entities into a POCO (`GridObject`).  In your case I don't think it's tripping anything but the fact that you've got a FK column in your source table with the `ResponsibleEmployeeId`, you might double-check that this value is actually Null.

Try the following:

```
var gridObjects = iQueryableObjectList.Select(obj => 
    new GridObject {
    {
        AddedByEmployeeId = obj.AddedByEmployeeId,
        AddedByEmployeeSignature = obj.AddedByEmployee.Signature,
        AddedDateTime = obj.Created,
        DocumentId = obj.DocumentId,
        ResponsibleEmployeeId = obj.ResponsibleEmployee.EmployeeId
        ResponsibleEmployee = obj.ResponsibleEmployee != null ? 
            obj.ReponsibleEmployee.FirstName + " " + obj.ResponsibleEmployee.LastName :
            companyName,
        Id = obj.Id,
        IsCompanyWide = obj.IsCompanyWide
    });
```

There are a few "quirks" to LINQ to Entities, depending on what has already gone into getting the `iQueryableObjectList` out of EF, considering it probably hasn't been materialized yet you could also be tripping on one of those. I get `NullReferenceException`s and odd behaviour sometimes when trying to saturate a POCO ViewModel while using operations with potentially null entities. Typically I aim to have my Queryables saturate the resulting entities or an intermediary anonymous type before attempting to saturate the POCO.

I.e.

```
var gridObjects = iQueryableObjectList.Select(obj => new 
    {
        AddedByEmployeeId = obj.AddedByEmployeeId,
        AddedByEmployeeSignature = obj.AddedByEmployee.Signature,
        AddedDateTime = obj.Created,
        DocumentId = obj.DocumentId,
        ResponsibleEmployeeId = obj.ResponsibleEmployeeId,
        ResponsibleEmployee = obj.ResponsibleEmployee,
        Id = obj.Id,
        IsCompanyWide = obj.IsCompanyWide
    }).ToList() // Saturates the entity data incl. Responsible Employee...
    .Select(obj => new GridObject
    {
        AddedByEmployeeId = obj.AddedByEmployeeId,
        AddedByEmployeeSignature = obj.AddedByEmployee.Signature,
        AddedDateTime = obj.Created,
        DocumentId = obj.DocumentId,
        ResponsibleEmployeeId = obj.ResponsibleEmployeeId,
        ResponsibleEmployee = obj.ResponsibleEmployee != null
          ? obj.ResponsibleEmployee.FirstName + " " + obj.ResponsibleEmployee.LastName 
          : companyName,
        Id = obj.Id,
        IsCompanyWide = obj.IsCompanyWide
    });
```

For view models I'll commonly keep them fairly "flat" relative to the data coming back. For instance, in your above example I'd consider having a `FirstName` & `LastName` column in `GridObject`, as well as a `CompanyName`, then have a computed property called `DisplayName`. From LINQ to Entities, the relevant bits to populate a POCO would become:

```
(Select new GridObject {
    ...
    FirstName = obj.ResponsibleEmployee.FirstName, // EF automatically handles cases where ResponsibleEmployee is Null
    LastName = obj.ResponsibleEmployee.LastName,
    CompanyName = companyName,
    ...
```

then in `GridObject` have a `DisplayName` that is computed based on `EmployeeId` and/or availability of Name data.

Comment: It's a good point but I if I do that `ToList()` I will practically cut the link between the IQueryable and the database. The framework I use has some methods that do sort and filter for tables and that link needs to be kept.

Comment: In some configuration mapping of that entity `ResponsibleEmployeeId` was required so when EF saw that it had a null value it simply ignored it.

Comment: Yeah, the .ToList() will effectively cut the tie for deferred load, but this should normally be occurring towards the end of your querying.   .Select() to saturate a view model or DTO like that should be one of the last operations. EF has no connotation of what a GridObject would be, so you should aim to be in a position to have resolved your "to SQL" querying by that point.  Flattening the name columns in the GridModel and having the comupted name there would do away with the .ToList() and probably resolve your issue.

Comment: As for the ResponsibleEmployeeId FK column, I avoid those as much as possible, and just use the navigation properties with the FK mapped behind the scenes by EF. The issue with having both is that there is easily the possibility that code could rely on either of both values. I.e. setting the ResponsibleEmployee to an entity with ID = 15 where the ResponsibleEmployeeId on the parent record is set to 12. Which is supposed to be correct? Having the FK there tempts people to use it or assume it automatically relates to the Navigation member.

Answer (score 0):

Try change the code `obj.ResponsibleEmployeeId != null` by `obj.ResponsibleEmployeeId != DBNull.Value`

```
var companyName = "Company";    

var gridObjects = iQueryableObjectList.Select(obj => new GridObject
            {
                AddedByEmployeeId = obj.AddedByEmployeeId,
                AddedByEmployeeSignature = obj.AddedByEmployee.Signature,
                AddedDateTime = obj.Created,
                DocumentId = obj.DocumentId,
                ResponsibleEmployeeId = obj.ResponsibleEmployeeId,
                ResponsibleEmployee = obj.ResponsibleEmployeeId != DBNull.Value ? 
                    obj.ResponsibleEmployee.FirstName + " " + obj.ResponsibleEmployee.LastName :
                    companyName,
                Id = obj.Id,
                IsCompanyWide = obj.IsCompanyWide
            });
```

Comment: It says that I cannot compare a Guid? to DBNull